# React Redux not updating state despite login working fine

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

So my reducers are not updating the state for my app. The initial state in user shows up with no changes made. The initial state from uiReducer doesn't come up at all. emphasized textI can log in okay and receive a token, so I think it is a problem with getUserData. I have no idea why the ui initial state isn't working however. This is my first time trying to use react redux so I probably have a dumb mistake somewhere. Any help appreciated!

EDIT: Without changing code, I just restarted my app and now both of the initial states are loading, but user is still not populated with data.

login

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'

// redux
import {connect} from 'react-redux'
import {loginUser} from '../redux/actions/userActions'

class login extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            email: '',
            password: '',
            errors: [],
        };
    }

    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
        if (nextProps.UI.errors) {
            this.setState({
                errors: nextProps.UI.errors
            });
        }
    }

    handleChange = (event) => {
        this.setState({
            [event.target.name]: event.target.value
        });
    };

    handleSubmit = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        const userData = {
            email: this.state.email,
            password: this.state.password
        };
        this.props.loginUser(userData, this.props.history)
    };

    render() {
        const { classes, UI: {loading} } = this.props;
        const { errors } = this.state;
        return (
            ..............
        );
    }
}
login.propTypes = {
    classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    loginUser: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    user: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    UI:PropTypes.object.isRequired

}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    user: state.user,
    UI: state.UI
})

const mapActionsToProps = {
    loginUser
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapActionsToProps)(withStyles(styles)(login));
```

userActions

```
import axios from 'axios';

export const loginUser = (userData, history) => (dispatch) => {
    dispatch({ type: 'LOADING_UI' });
    axios
        .post('/login', userData)
        .then((res) => {
            setAuthorizationHeader(res.data.token);
            dispatch(getUserData())
            dispatch({type: 'CLEAR_ERRORS'})
            history.push('/');
        })
        .catch((error) => {             
            dispatch({
                type: 'SET_ERRORS',
                payload: error.response.data
            });
        });

}

export const getUserData = ()=> (dispatch) => {
    axios
        .get('/user')
        .then(res => {
           dispatch({
               type: 'SET_USER',
               payload: res.data
           })
        })

}

const setAuthorizationHeader = (token) => {
    const FBIdToken = `Bearer ${token}`;
    localStorage.setItem('FBIdToken', FBIdToken);
    axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = FBIdToken;
};
```

userReducer

```
const initialState = {
    authenticated: false,
    credentials: {},
    approves: []
}

export default function(state = initialState, action){
    switch(action.type){
        case 'SET_AUTHENTICATED':
            return{
                ...state,
                authenticated: true
            }
        case 'SET_UNAUTHENTICATED':
            return initialState
        case 'SET_USER':
            return{
                authenticated: true,
                loading: false,
                ...action.payload
            }
        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

uiReducer

```
const initialState = {
    loading: false,
    errors: null
}
export default function(state = initialState, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
      case 'SET_ERRORS':
        return {
          ...state,
          loading: false,
          errors: action.payload
        };
      case 'CLEAR_ERRORS':
        return {
          ...state,
          loading: false,
          errors: null
        };
      case 'LOADING_UI':
        return {
          ...state,
          loading: true
        };
        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

I'm really confused that I can log in fine, but the state isnt updated, and only the user state is initialized..

EDIT:
store.js

```
import { createStore, combineReducers, applyMiddleware, compose } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';

import userReducer from './reducers/userReducer';
import dataReducer from './reducers/dataReducer';
import uiReducer from './reducers/uiReducer';

const initialState = {};

const middleware = [thunk];

const reducers = combineReducers({
  user: userReducer,
  data: dataReducer,
  UI: uiReducer
});



const store = createStore(reducers, 
    initialState, 
    compose(
        applyMiddleware(...middleware),
        window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__()
    )
);

export default store;
```

Comment: Can you post the code where you have `createStore` and `combineReducers`?  I wonder if you forgot to include the UI reducer.   I feels like a really bad practice to call `history.push('/')` inside of an action creator but I don't know if it's an error.

Comment: I just added the store code, I could change the ```history.push('/')``` but the state should be updated before its run in any case, no?

Comment: To get the state to update when you login you need a componentdidmount? I’m not too familiar with class components.

Answer (score 0):

Changing `...action.payload` to `user: action.payload` seems to have fixed it. I got the code for this section from a tutorial but the syntax must have been slightly outdated or something, who knows

```
export default function(state = initialState, action){
    switch(action.type){
        case 'SET_AUTHENTICATED':
            return{
                ...state,
                authenticated: true
            }
        case 'SET_UNAUTHENTICATED':
            return initialState
        case 'SET_USER':
            return{
                authenticated: true,
                loading: false,
                user: action.payload
            }
        default:
            return state
    }
}
```